# Counting rows each specific characters

Tags: r, dataframe

Dear colleagues I have a dataset with multiple columns that indicate the number of machine and the number of variable recorded, something as:

```
Machine           Name1(A01)  Name2(A02)  Name3(A03)  ...    Name1(A01)
Signal            Signal1     Signal 1    Signal 1    ...    Signal124
Timestamp Unit    Unit        Unit        Unit
2017-11-01 00:00  value1      value1
2017-11-01 00:30  value2      value2
2017-11-01 01:00    .
      .             .
      .             .
```

I would like to know if it is possible to filter the values of signalX by the number (Ayx) and storage these values in a matrix.

Basically I have to storage the values like:

```
filter the values

Signal1[i,j]=
Signal2[i,j]=
```

Being i the number of machines and t the timestamp

Comment: I am unclear on exactly what you're trying to do. Can you give an example of the kind of filter operation you want to do and your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then one of the approach could be

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- t(df) %>%
  data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  `colnames<-`(.[1,]) %>%
  filter(row_number()!=1) %>%
  gather(Timestamp, signal_value, -Machine, -Signal, -Timestamp_unit)
```

which will output

```
> df1
   Machine    Signal Timestamp_unit        Timestamp signal_value
1      A01   Signal1           Unit 2017-11-01 00:00       value1
2      A02   Signal1           Unit 2017-11-01 00:00     value1_1
3      A03   Signal2           Unit 2017-11-01 00:00     value1_2
4      A04 Signal124           Unit 2017-11-01 00:00     value1_3
5      A01   Signal1           Unit 2017-11-01 00:30       value2
6      A02   Signal1           Unit 2017-11-01 00:30     value2_1
7      A03   Signal2           Unit 2017-11-01 00:30     value2_2
8      A04 Signal124           Unit 2017-11-01 00:30     value2_3
9      A01   Signal1           Unit 2017-11-01 01:00       value3
10     A02   Signal1           Unit 2017-11-01 01:00     value3_1
11     A03   Signal2           Unit 2017-11-01 01:00     value3_2
12     A04 Signal124           Unit 2017-11-01 01:00     value3_3
```

Now you can easily query your desired value as

```
df1[df1$Signal=='Signal1' & df1$Machine=='A02' & df1$Timestamp=='2017-11-01 00:00', "signal_value"]
#[1] "value1_1"
```

**Sample data**

```
df <- read.table(text="Machine       A01         A02      A03      A04
                 Signal              Signal1     Signal1  Signal2  Signal124
                 Timestamp_unit      Unit        Unit     Unit     Unit
                 '2017-11-01 00:00'  value1      value1_1 value1_2 value1_3
                 '2017-11-01 00:30'  value2      value2_1 value2_2 value2_3
                 '2017-11-01 01:00'  value3      value3_1 value3_2 value3_3", header=T, stringsAsFactor=F)
```